# Not authorized to access Kafka Connect internal topics in remote cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup kafka jdbc sink connector in Machine A, in which I have to connect to kafka topic which is in remote machine B. I have tried producer and consumer through ssl certs and worked well in machine A. Now I am trying to create jdbc sink connector in machine A through the same SSL cert, but getting below error. I have given the producer, consumer SSL config properties in connect distributed file. The topic in the error is internal connect topics created in machine B(remote).

Please suggest me if i miss anything and how to resolve it.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while attempting to create/find topic(s) 'connect-offset-storage-topic'
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:255)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore$1.run(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:126)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:109)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:174)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:109)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:215)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed.]
  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:262)
  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:228)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [Topic authorization failed.]
```

Comment: Are your certificates valid for the offsets, status, and storage topics for Kafka Connect or only the topic you're consuming from? The issue isn't the topic being remote

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for reply. Yes, certs are valid for internal topics and as well the topic which i am consuming. I am using ssl connection, do i need to do anything like jaas by providing user and password..

Comment: Could you give more context about how the certificates are created, which CA is used and how keystores and trustores are deployed on various machines? Also, could you please inspect what are the current ACL on that topic (something like `kafka-acls  --topic connect-offset-storage-topic --list ... ` ) ? Finally, could you please clarify i f `connect-offset-storage-topic` is created explicitly by you or is it created automatically by connect ? Thanks in advance